# Laravel 6 session() helper is not working?

Tags: php, session, laravel-6

I have this very simple class:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class HomeController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
//        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    public function home(Request $request)
    {
        echo "setting help key";
        session()->put('help', 'me');
        session(['sos' => 'me']);
        dump(session('help'));
        dump(session('sos'));
    }

    public function home2(Request $request)
    {
        dump(session('help'));
        dump(session('sos'));
    }
//...
```

which dumps the vars successfully in the home() page, but when i access to the home2() page, it fails. Maybe it has something to do with me disabling the default `middleware('auth')`, but i'm not sure (also, if that is the case, how to use sessions without forcing the login)

Answer (score 2):

try

```
session(['key' => 'value']); // to store
```

```
session()->get('key'); // to get the value
```

```
session()->forget('key'); // to unset the session attribute
```

---

read also: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/session (change the Laravel version at the top-right corner...)

---

P.S. Sometimes you can't just dump data. Try `var_export` or what's better, just debug.

Comment: As you can see in the code i added in my question, i´ve already tried with the syntax commented in the docs to store, as well as the one to get the value. I even tried another one not very explicit in the docs
Also, if a variable´s dump returns `null`, then there´s no point in trying to "debug" it with another function. And more, if the framework provides apparently simple ways to use a session, then it shouln't be so difficult to see what's in it.

PD: have you tried the code i posted? Did you had the same issue, or it worked ok?

Comment: I've never heard of `dump`, actually. I used `var_dump`. Try and see what happens. Maybe your `dump` function destroys the session or clears all attributes. I'm not sure. I'm not a PHP developer. However, I'm familiar with.

Comment: Look, the problem is, I have made Laravel applications too, and the sessions work just as expected. Every single Laravel-developer will state for sure that sessions work. That's not a magic and it is just a fact. I just have had a similar problem when I stored and got session attributes in other way than I wrote in my answer. That's why I thought you had same issues.

Comment: Because it is not that clear what happens in your code (maybe you redirect from post to get = PGR pattern) it is not easy to find out the problem you have. It is possible that you will see what's in your session if you write `var_dump(session()->get('key'); die;`. However, it is not excluded that even in that case you won't see anything. That's why I would prefer to debug.

Comment: When you redirect you can also write: `redirect('route')->with('key', 'value');` this is the way you show kind-of post reports (that are unset automatically from the session.

Comment: Sometimes you need to change some folder permissions or configure your application for sessions. However, I can guarantee that sessions in Laravel work as intended. I mean, try to find a solution instead of trying to prove that sessions don't work in Laravel.